# Code to triangulate a set of 2d points

Tags: triangulation

I am trying to create a triangulated mesh from 100,000 2d data points and export to an obj. Any suggestions about code to do this? I have created my own Delaunay triangulation algorithm but it takes 45 minutes to run on a Xeon X5650.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a homework solving site. What have you tried so far? If you know you have tried something, how do we know what you have tried so far? (as you are not mentioning anything about your attempt)

Comment: @PrasadRaghavendra doing this as a hobby, never went to school for this and the delaunay was the best I could find while researching online. Downvoting a 2 year old question is not cool, although I'm not here to build reputation so whatever

Comment: my objective was to make your question better and get whatever help you may need. I do not care so much about SO reputation either. But, when I was searching for something similar myself, I, like you, would have been helped if your question were to have been better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing about you implementation it is still clear that 45 minutes for 100K of vertices is too much, this can be done in seconds without the need for special hardware. There are several libraries out there that can do that: (1) [Triangle](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake/triangle.html) is widely used and quite fast, (2) [CGAL](https://www.cgal.org) as the heavy weight framework in this area, and there are many more.